# firebase delete object from field array by index

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How to delete object from array field by array index? or suggest another way!

i want to choose object from files array and delete!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no `choose and delete` method from an array in cloud firestore. What you can do is get that array to a temporary array and remove the object that you need to delete from the array and overwrite the document `array field` with your newly updated temporary array.

```
const deleteObjFromArr = async (index) => {
    try {
        /*
         * Get the files array to a temporary array.
         * If you have already gotten the document to an object,
         * assign the object field to the temporary array
         */
        
        const docRef = firebase.firestore().collection('tasks-collection').doc('tasks');
        const tempArr = (await docRef.get()).files;
        
        // Remove object from array
        tempArr.splice(index, 1);
        
        // Save new array in cloud firestore
        await docRef.update({ files: tempArr });
        console.log('Files array updated successfully');
        
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error occured. Operation terminated.');
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

Comment: Now i got another problem, i realise that delete by index bad idea, cause index will change anyway after removal, maybe possible somehow find by some keyword inside array and delete whole array element?

Comment: yes @AwKingOftheworld, you can. You can use `filter` method of array to filter out the array which do not have that finding key.

`tempArr = tempArr.filter(e => e.attributeName != findingKeyword)`